# Php error log Filled up with PHP Deprecated: Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated

Tags: php, error-logging

I've recently installed php and mysql in a new windows server IIS and transferred my script there, there's a problem that after enabling error log in php manager, I just get one line  error repeatedly for everything as this:
`PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0`

at the old server, error log was working great and php version is 7.4.33 in both of them.

all error loggers in php.ini is set to true but the problem still is remained in place.
if I set track_errors=Off then no error will be logged in php_errors.log

Any idea of why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've solved the problem by changing the permission of `Temp` Folder.

Before changing the Temp directory permission, I've tried using a different php.ini, the `php.ini-development` one, and then error log started logging, comparing my original php.ini and the new one, I've found these 3 lines maybe causing the problem as I removed them and system started logging again

```
upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Windows\Temp\"
cgi.force_redirect = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
```

But as there were more different configs in file, I've started checking permissions!

Temp folder had a full access permission for IIS_USER, but for Users, it was just a limited permission. after I've changed the permission for Users to Full Access, the problem solved and errors started to show up in error log file again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not an error, it's a notice. Notice of depreciation as the beginning suggests. You can check what each log level means in PHP [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

> 8192  E_DEPRECATED (int)  Run-time notices. Enable this to receive
> warnings about code that will not work in future versions.

Secondly, you fixed it by setting `track_errors` to `Off`. That functionality is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php), which means that it will be removed in future versions and you should be discouraged from using it.

> track_errors  "0" PHP_INI_ALL Deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0, removed as of
> PHP 8.0.0.

If you want to keep that enabled and get rid of the depreciation notices, you can change `error_reporting` value listed on page above to not include them by adding `~E_DEPRECATED` to it.

Comment: Thanks for your information, the `Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated` is the ONLY message that appears in error log in several lines and if I turn it off, then no record will be added to the file. so I think some parameters are not set correctly and wondering what it can be necause in previous server everything was working great

Comment: You didn't understand/follow what I wrote. This PHP notice is caused by what I specified. It's normal to appear on PHP 7.4.33 version when the feature was deprecated in 7.2.0. If you had the same version on your previous server as you're claiming and it didn't appear, then the difference is in `error_reporting` value.